# Using tab key for navigation in TextEdit

Tags: qml, qt-quick

I have two `TextEdit` boxes and one custom button widget, I wish to change focus in the following order using the tab key on my keyboard:

```
TextEdit1 <-> TextEdit2 <-> Button
```

I have specified something similar to the following for each widget in order to obtain the chain above:

```
KeyNavigation.tab: TextEdit2
KeyNavigation.backtab: TextEdit1
```

My problem is however that the tab keystroke is caught in the `TextEdit`, and cannot be used to navigate. How can I disable tabs in the `TextEdit` and instead use it for changing focus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem.

By default the key events are first sent to the item which is receiving the event - not to  `KeyNavigation`. This behavior can be changed by setting

```
KeyNavigation.priority: KeyNavigation.BeforeItem
```

The complete code thus becomes

```
KeyNavigation.tab: TextEdit2
KeyNavigation.backtab: TextEdit1
KeyNavigation.priority: KeyNavigation.BeforeItem
```

Answer (score 3):

Read about the [Qml Keys element](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qml-keys.html).

You can do something like this :

```
TextEdit
{
  width : 40
  height: 40
  text  : "junk"

  Keys.onTabPressed: 
  {
      // Write logic to transfer focus to whomsoever you want
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I thought about this, but the KeyNavigation approach seems cleaner - do you know if there is a way in which I can use KeyNavigation instead?

Comment: Now I found the setting! Thank you for this alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

While searching for a solution to a similar problem, I came across this option in Qt Creator and seems to solve the thing. Now I can move out of the QTextEdit object with tab key, instead of inserting a tab character into the field.

I see that the topic is old and already solved but maybe this convenient simple option was made available with a more recent update to Qt, I don't know. I just came across it and I hope it helps someone searching for the same solution as me.

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP question which is about QML/QtQuick

Comment: true, yet it helped me :-)
but Dogukan's answer belongs in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146509/pressing-tab-in-qtextedit-in-dialog-change-behavior