# Pressing Tab in QTextEdit in Dialog - change behavior

Tags: qt, qt4, qtextedit, qdialog

I have `QDialog` that contains few buttons and a `QTextEdit`.
after writing something in the `QTextEdit`, I press tab in order to get to one of the buttons, but when I pressing tab, a tab space is added to the `QTextEdit`. How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [setTabChangesFocus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#tabChangesFocus-prop) method of `QTextEdit`:

```
yourTextEdit.setTabChangesFocus(true);
```

Comment: Works for PyQt5 as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass `QTextEdit` and override the `keyPressEvent` to intercept the tab key. Then, use `nextInFocusChain` to determine the next focus widget and call `setFocus` on it

Outline:

```
class MyTextEdit : public QTextEdit
{
public:
    MyTextEdit(QWidget *parent = 0) : QTextEdit(parent) {}

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e) {
        if (e->key() == Qt::Key_Tab) {
            nextInFocusChain()->setFocus(Qt::TabFocusReason);
        } else {
            QTextEdit::keyPressEvent(e);
        }
    }
};
```